# How to create an object containing a range of values for a key

Tags: javascript, object

I'm trying to create an object that should hold a range of values for a key which I would use as a look-up table. For example, it needs to "catch" values in the ranges: 500-524, 600-650, etc..

e.g.:

```
const numbers = {
  500 to 524: "20",
  600 to 650: "25"
}
```

And I would like to access the value in the following way:

`user.list.map(list => numbers[user.points])`.

I know I can put all the values from the range as keys but that would be highly inefficient:

```
const numbers = {
  "500": "20",
  "501": "20",
  "502": "20",
  "503": "20",
  (...)
}
```

So, is it possible to include ranges somehow?

Comment: Simply try `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(number)); `.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking, unfortunately. Objects use string keys, there is no such thing as "x through y", that's an array thing. Also, what is `500 at 524: "20",` supposed to actually _mean_? Because that's illegal JS, so it's not helping illustrate what kind of thing you're trying to build.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans it would be a simplified way of going from 500 to 524, without putting 501, 502, 503, 504, 505, 506, etc.

Comment: Okay, so what does that mean? What _real_ object do you expect to have at the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set it up like this:

```js
numbers = [
  {"start": 500, "end": 524, "value": "20"},
  ...
  ...
]

function getFromNumbers(num) {
  for(let i=0; i<numbers.length; i++) {
    numVal = numbers[i];
    if(numVal.start <= num && numVal.end >= num)
      return numVal.value;
  }
}

console.log(user.list.map(list => getFromNumbers(user.points)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create an object like this:

```
const numbers =
[
    {
        start : 500
        end : 524
        value :20
    },
    {
        start : 600
        end : 650
        value : 25
     }
]
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you should inverse the solution. You can create object, where `key` is `"20"` and `value` is array of values. For example:

```
const numbers = {
    "20": _.range(500, 524)
}
```